# Can we use libemu library in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I found that libemu library is used in C language for detecting Shellcode in a string. Can we use the same in javascript? If so can you explain it with an example. If not can you suggest another alternative libraries in Javascript which does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript does not have Libemu but we have two x86 emulators